# SQL - CASE WHEN Error?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

Could somebody help me out? I'm not sure why this code keeps not executing:

```
'0' || CASE
WHEN (EAmain.ActivityStopMin - EAmain.ActivityStartMin) < 0 THEN         (DATEDIFF(hh,EAmain.ActivityStartTimeHours || ':' ||     EAmain.ActivityStartTimeMin,EAmain.ActivityStopTimeHours || ':' ||     EAmain.ActivityStopTimeMin)-1)
WHEN (EAmain.ActivityStopMin - EAmain.ActivityStartMin) >= 0 THEN
(DATEDIFF(hh,EAmain.ActivityStartTimeHours || ':' ||     EAmain.ActivityStartTimeMin,EAmain.ActivityStopTimeHours || ':' ||     EAmain.ActivityStopTimeMin))
END || ':' || (DATEDIFF(n,EAmain.ActivityStartTimeHours || ':' ||     EAmain.ActivityStartTimeMin,EAmain.ActivityStopTimeHours || ':' ||     EAmain.ActivityStopTimeMin)#60) || '0' AS ActivityTotalTime,
```

EDIT:
I found the error code, here it is:

ERROR #5540: SQLCODE: -29 Message: Field 'EAMAIN.ACTIVITYSTOPMIN' not found in the applicable tables^ SELECT Name , Start_Time , Stop_Time , Visit_Date , Total_Time , ActivityStartTime , ActivityStopTime , CASE WHEN LEN ( ActivityTotalTime ) = ? THEN SUBSTR ( ActivityTotalTime , ? , ? ) WHEN LEN ( ActivityTotalTime ) = ? THEN ActivityTotalTime END AS ActivityTotalTime , Discipline FROM ( SELECT Demographics . Name , Visits . Start_Time , Visits . Stop_Time , Visits . Visit_Date , Visits . Total_Time , EAmain . ActivityStartTime , EAmain . ActivityStopTime , ? || CASE WHEN ( EAmain . ActivityStopMin -

EDIT AGAIN!:
This code was what was implemented before the CASE statement, and it worked:

```
'0' || DATEDIFF(hh,EAmain.ActivityStartTimeHours || ':' ||    
EAmain.ActivityStartTimeMin,EAmain.ActivityStopTimeHours || ':' ||     
EAmain.ActivityStopTimeMin) || ':' || (DATEDIFF(n,EAmain.ActivityStartTimeHours || ':' || 
EAmain.ActivityStartTimeMin,EAmain.ActivityStopTimeHours || ':' ||    
EAmain.ActivityStopTimeMin)#60) || '0' AS ActivityTotalTime,
```

Comment: It's only a small part of a query. But do you get any error messages?

Comment: Not anything specific :(

Comment: So we just have to guess? I assume you get either a syntax error or a runtime error.

Comment: Well that's clear then: the field ACTIVITYSTOPMIN doesn't exist in EAmain.

Comment: Yes it does. As I said below, the whole query worked fine until the CASE statement was added. It has something to do with my CASE syntax

Comment: Please see my modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>On the last line you got `EAmain.ActivityStartTimeMin,EAmain.ActivityStopTimeHours`. That comma seems to be misplaced. As is the `)#60)` a couple of characters further on that last line.</strike>

EAmain.ACTIVITYSTOPMIN  doesn't exist. :) I see in your error message that EMain isn't a table but a query. Make sure you select that field in the query as well.

Comment: No that is how it is supposed to be. This whole code worked until I added the CASE statement to check if the stopmin-startmin value was negative.

Comment: See my modified response^ please

Comment: @phileaton: Could you please post the before code that worked?

Comment: @phileaton in the code before the CASE statement, you did not refer to the field `ActivityStopMin` at all. Are you sure you don't mean `ActivityStopTimeMin` or something? Please read your code closely. The case statement is the only place where `ActivityStopMin` is used. It's no syntax error.

Comment: Wonderful, I'm very sorry for my ignorance, that worked perfectly! Sorry, and thank you!